# Why use "has" instead of "have" in "Has your course started yet?", since it is in the second person?

Tags: verbs, singular-vs-plural, questions

I saw this question in the book "English Grammar in Use, Fifth Edition" by Louise Hashemi on page 15, the question is:

> ...(your course/start yet)?

> Not Yet. It starts next week.

And the answer given is:

> Has your course started yet?

Why do we use "Has" here instead of "Have"? From what I [know about “has” and “have”](https://www.thesaurus.com/e/grammar/has-vs-have/), when speaking in the second person, we should use "Have".

Comment: Because the verb refers to the course and not 'you'! The course either has or has not started.

Comment: The subject is the course, so the question is in third person singular. The answer, indeed, is "It (the course) starts next week".

Comment: It looks to me as if the question has a mistake, and should read _...(you**r** course/start yet)?_  A possible answer from the question as posed would be _Have you started your course yet?_ - in that case the subject is _you_, so the verb is _have_, as yout hought.

Comment: Please check that you have quoted the example correctly.  I don't think this can be answered until that is confirmed

Comment: @ColinFine The question is indeed (your course), sorry for my mistake.

Comment: Then @KateBunting's explanation holds, if she'd care to make an official answer of it...

Comment: @kate-bunting Any reason for not turning your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Has started* refers to the course. The fact that it is described as *your course* is irrelevant to the choice of verb.

Answer (score -3):

Whether it is “has” or “have,” neither is grammatical.

> Has your course start yet

and

> Have your course start yet

would never be said by a sober native speaker over the age of three.

Comment: Presumably part of the exercise was to put the verb _start_ in the correct tense!

Comment: It seems to be a “fill in the blank” type of question, shown by the … Nothing indicates that any other words are in question. Nor did the original poster indicate any doubt about the failure to use the perfect participle. “Didn’t” is the only word that makes sense as an answer to the question as asked.